# Bind columns (from vectors) for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The codes are like this:

```
a = numpy.zeros(3)
b = numpy.ones(3)
bind_by_column((a,b))
=> [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
```

I checked [this](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html) but don't find the answer

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `numpy.vstack()`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros(3)
>>> b = numpy.ones(3)
>>> numpy.vstack((a,b)).T
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 15):

np.column_stack

see
[Numpy: Concatenating multidimensional and unidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158388/numpy-concatenating-multidimensional-and-unidimensional-arrays/4158985#4158985)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros(3)
>>> b = numpy.ones(3)
>>> numpy.column_stack((a,b))
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```