# Concatenating two numpy array issues

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of shape

```
(129873, 12)
(129873,)
```

I would like to concatenate these so they are in the shape of:

```
(129873, 13)
```

I have tried `numpy.concatenate` and `numpy.vstack` but seem to be getting errors:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one array has 2 dimensions, the other 1:

```
(129873, 12)
(129873,)
```

You need to change the 2nd to have shape `(129873,1)`.  Then you can concatenate on axis 1.

There are a number of way of do this.  The `[:,None]` or `np.newaxis` indexing is my favorite:

```
In [648]: A=np.ones((3,4),int)

In [649]: B=np.ones((3,),int)

In [650]: B[:,None].shape
Out[650]: (3, 1)

In [651]: np.concatenate((A,B[:,None]),axis=1).shape
Out[651]: (3, 5)
```

`B.reshape(-1,1)` also works. Also `np.atleast_2d(B).T` and `np.expand_dims(B,1)`.

`np.column_stack((A,B))` uses `np.array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T` to ensure each array has the right number of dimensions.

While there are friendly covers to `concatenate` like `column_stack`, it's important to know how to change dimensions directly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this was already answered here:

[Numpy: Concatenating multidimensional and unidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158388/numpy-concatenating-multidimensional-and-unidimensional-arrays?rq=1)

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
b = numpy.array([5, 6, 6])
c = numpy.column_stack((a,b))
print a
print b
print c
print a.shape
print b.shape
print c.shape
```

This gives you:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5]]
[5 6 6]
[[1 2 3 4 5 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]]
(3, 5)
(3,)
(3, 6)
```